# Putting text on top of "foreground objects" detected by OpenCV's background subtraction

Tags: python, opencv

In a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429091/combining-features-of-all-videos-using-python) I asked about how one could go about blending foreground objects from multiple video frames and combining them. Stephen gave me a hint on using background subtraction. I built on top of it and posted my answer. It works surprisingly well, because it seems to effectively make "foreground objects" things that move, and background objects "things that remain static" over a period of time. I find it superior for my needs to using OpenCV cascades (only for people and many misses) and DNNs (DNNs are much more accurate, but too slow for my needs).

So given a mask of foreground objects, how do I go about putting some text, say "Detected!" on top of each 'disconnected blob' in the mask?

Consider the image here https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html - let's look at "Result of BackgroundSubtractorMOG2"

[image]

- as you see, there are 7 mostly disconnected blobs. How does one find the top coordinates of each such blob so I can put some text? It's okay if it occasionally fails.

thanks

Comment: You should use the `boundingRect()` function of the OpenCV which returns a rectangle and you can get the `x,y, width, height` of a blob.

Comment: Thanks - looks like I had to first to a findContours and then use boundingRect

Comment: You are welcome! You can also filter out the shadows by setting the shadow value to zero e.g: `mog2.setShadowValue(0);`