# Improving background extraction with shiny objects (OpenCV/Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I've been working on a 'fun' solution that combines multiple videos from a security camera into one video, the idea being to overlay foreground motion over many hours into a few seconds for a 'quick preview'. Thanks to [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429091/combining-features-of-all-videos-using-python) and [Bahramdum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464685/putting-text-on-top-of-foreground-objects-detected-by-opencvs-background-subt) for getting me on the right path.

The project is [open source](https://github.com/pliablepixels/zmMagik), for anyone to see. So far, I've played with the following background extractions:

- OpenCV BackgroundSubtraction using a variety of algorithms
- Mask R-CNN
- Yolov3/TinyYolo
- Optical flow
- (I haven't yet tried detection+centroid tracking, will do so next)

Based on my experiments so far, OpenCV's background extraction generally works the best due to the fact that it extracts foreground purely based on motion. Plus its very fast. True, that it also extracts things like moving leaves etc, but we can work on removing those.

**Here is an example of 3 hours of video blended into one short video**.
https://youtu.be/C-mJfzvFTdg

**My current challenge is that it is doing a bad job with shiny objects, like cars.**

Here is an example:

[image]

Background subtraction consistently does a bad job with extracting polygons for shiny objects and `findContours` does no better either.

I've tried several options, but my current approach is documented [here](https://github.com/pliablepixels/zmMagik/blob/master/zmMagik_helpers/detect_background.py#L34-L67), the gist of which is:

1. Convert frame to HSV
2. remove intensity (I read this in another SO thread for shiny objects)
3. Apply background subtraction
4. Clean up outside noise with MORPH_OPEN
5. Blur mask to hopefully connect near while blobs
6. find contours on new masks
7. only keep contours of certain min area
8. create a new mask, where we draw only these contours with fill
9. Do a final dilation to connect close filled contours of new masks
   10.Use this new mask to extract foreground from the frame and overlay it with current blended video

Would anyone have suggestions on how to improve extraction for reflective objects?

```
 self.fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=False,    
    history=self.history) 
    frame_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    frame_hsv[:,:,0] = 0 # see if removing intensity helps
   # gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_hsv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # create initial background subtraction
    frame_mask = self.fgbg.apply(frame_hsv)
    # remove noise
    frame_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(frame_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, self.kernel_clean)
    # blur to merge nearby masks, hopefully
    frame_mask = cv2.medianBlur(frame_mask,15)
    #frame_mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame_mask,(5,5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
    #frame_mask = cv2.blur(frame_mask,(20,20))

    h,w,_ = frame.shape
    new_frame_mask = np.zeros((h,w),dtype=np.uint8)
    copy_frame_mask = frame_mask.copy()
    # find contours of mask
    relevant = False
    ctrs,_ =  cv2.findContours(copy_frame_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    rects = []
    # only select relevant contours 
    for contour in ctrs:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area >= self.min_blend_area:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            pts = Polygon([[x,y], [x+w,y], [x+w, y+h], [x,y+h]])
            if g.poly_mask is None or g.poly_mask.intersects(pts):
                relevant = True
                cv2.drawContours(new_frame_mask, [contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
                rects.append([x,y,w,h])

    # do a dilation to again, combine the contours
    frame_mask = cv2.dilate(new_frame_mask,self.kernel_fill,iterations = 5)
    frame_mask = new_frame_mask
```

Comment: try with createBackgroundSubtractorMOG increase the variable int history=400. This means you a taking longer average history. Which the car travel there and go wont be last for more than 100 frame, therefore it is outlier for the 400 frame ago average.

Comment: also adjust the background ratio variable.  This
threshold defining whether the component is significant enough to be included into the background model. TB=0.9 is default. For alpha=0.001, it means that the mode should exist for approximately 105 frames before it is considered foreground.  I think you should try out various  parameter in the bgfg model to get perfect segmentation output

Comment: Thank you. I first tried with MOG. I did not find it to offer improvements, but I agree, playing with parameters may help. I'll keep trying

Comment: anyway, interesting project. worth a thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

I found way too many variations on different conditions to have something predictable using openCV's background extraction

So I switched to yolov3 for object identification (added it as a new option, actually). While TinyYOLO was pretty terrible, YoloV3 seems to be adequate, albeit much slower.

Unfortunately, given YoloV3 only does rectangle and not subject masks, I had to switch to `addWeighted` method of cv2 to blend a new object on top of the blended frame.

Example: https://github.com/pliablepixels/zmMagik/blob/master/sample/1.gif